# Building gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a gradle plugin alongside with a project:

```
plugin_consumer
  |
  + build.gradle
  + src/

plugin
  |
  + build.gradle 
  + libs/
  + src/
```

All jars are moved to `plugin/libs` after built, and `plugin consumer` module uses plugin like so:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
  // ...
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath fileTree(dir:'../plugin/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  }
} 

apply plugin: 'my.custom.plugin'
```

I tested and this setup worked fine, however the plugin `.jar` is being built without dependencies, and as soon as I add some dependencies to the project the consumer buildscript started crashing because  of `NoClassDefFoundError` exceptions. The problem is when I build a **fat jar** instead  the script no longer finds plugin:

```
// from plugin/build.gradle 
// Configurations to build jar with dependencies
configurations {
  jar.archiveName = 'plugin.jar'
}
jar {
  archiveName = 'plugin.jar'
  baseName = project.name + '-all'
  from { configurations.compile.collect {
    println it
    it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
  } }
}
```

Running commands on `plugin_consumer` project throws error:

```
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'my.custom.plugin']
   > Plugin with id 'my.custom.plugin' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't identified the problem, but have found a solution. Somehow the `jar` instruction to package all of the sources have messed up the plugin jar file. The following configurations have worked on plugin side instead:

```
//...
jar {
  from {
    configurations.compileWithDependencies.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}

configurations {
  compileWithDependencies
}

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
  compileWithDependencies 'my.dependency1'
  compileWithDependencies 'my.dependency1'
  testCompile 'test.dependency'

  configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.compileWithDependencies)
}
```

From the looks of it I would guess that `gradleApi()` dependencies should not be compiled into the plugin jar.